# How do you test if String is in URL format?

Tags: java, android, string, url, format

Okay, there must be an easy approach I'm missing here, but I'm drawing a blank. I have a custom `ListView` that gets some of its images from files on the external storage, some from the internet, and if neither of those it displays a PNG file from the drawable folder. For my logic, I need to be able to tell if a `String` (image location) is an URL type or File type.

So, how would I be able to tell if a `String` is in URL format or File format?

Comment: Couldnt you check the protocol? Like file:// for local and http:// or similar for url? and if local files are of type /mnt/sdcard while urls are of type protocol://domain/path . Is it that hard?

Comment: That is a possibility, of course, I would have to use something like `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()` rather than hard coding `/mnt/sdcard`. `Is it that hard?` - that's a matter of personal perception and is irrelevant to the question asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A malformed URL will give you an exception.  To know if you the URL is active or not you have to perform a handshake with the URL.

There is no other way that I know of.

Answer (score 4):

Use `URI` to try and parse your string:

```
try {
    new URI(theString);
} catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    // Certainly not an URL
}
```

You will have to make additional checks, such as checking this URI's scheme (or calling `.toURL()` on it and check that it does not throw a `MalformedURLException`).

Comment: It looks like checking to see if it throws a `MalformedUrlException` is the best approach. Thanks a lot I appreciate it!

Comment: Yes, though your answer is more in-depth, the general concept is the same and the accepted answer was first. However, I gave you a +1 for the detail. Thanks!